# Custom Access Rules for Spring Security

Tags: spring, security, spring-security

Typically you define some intercept-url patterns to configure access to pages with spring security

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/secure/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_SECURE_USER')" />
    ...
</http>
```

We now have pages with url's that are not known beforehand. But we can write a piece of code to decide whether a specific page should be protected or not, i.e. we can provide a service that returns true if the page has to be protected. So what we'd like to do is something like this:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept decide="@service.mustProtect()" access="hasRole('ROLE_SECURE_USER')" />
    ...
</http>
```

How can this be achieved with Spring? Do we have to write a custom filter? How would you implement such a filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it was quite easy to solve our problem by injecting a custom filter just before the `FilterSecurityInterceptor`. You can then throw an `AccessDeniedException` in the filter's `doFilter` method to trigger authentication.

Spring security config:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <custom-filter before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" ref="accessFilter"/>
    ...
</http>

<beans:bean id="accessFilter" class="xyz.AccessFilter" />
```

Filter:

```
public class AccessFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (!currentUserCanAccessPage(request)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }
        chain.doFilter(request,response)
    }

    private boolean currentUserCanAccessPage(ServletRequest request) {
        //implement
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What the `<intercept-url>` tags do is simply populating a repository (called `SecurityMetadataSource`) where `RequestMatcher`s are mapped to `ConfigAttribute`s. `RequestMatcher`s are generated based on the `pattern` attribute, while `ConfigAttribute`s are just holding the string specified in the `access` attribute.

When an incoming request hits the `FilterSecurityInterceptor` filter, it will iterate over the list of these mappings to find the first entry, where the `RequestMatcher` indicates a match, in order to determine what kind of access restrictions it has to enforce (described by the mapped `ConfigAttribute`).

Now, if you could put your own `RequestMatcher` implementation to this map, your requirement would be basically solved. The difficulty is that the namespace configuration does not cater for this use-case, it's only able to interpret the `pattern` attribute either as `AntPathRequestMatcher` or as `RegexRequestMatcher`.

This means that you will have to configure the security infrastructure at the bean level, because the `<http>` element creates its own `FilterSecurityInterceptor` that cannot be replaced.

In [this article](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/03/06/behind-the-spring-security-namespace/) you can find great help on how to write this kind of manual security configuration.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a custom filter in front of the `FilterSecurityInterceptor` which throws a `AccessDeniedException` if the current user is not allowed to access the page?

Comment: Sure, good point, the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` doesn't care about where the `AccessDeniedException` was thrown. It doesn't have to come from a customized `FilterSecurityInterceptor`. You can provide your own filters as well, and it might be significantly easier to set up.