# Is it possible to persist a security configuration and dynamically change it?

Tags: java, spring, security

I'm using `Spring security 3`. I'm trying to solve the following problem. I need to persist a security configuration for intercepted urls and provide the ability to dynamically change it. For instance:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/super/**" access="ROLE_WE_DONT_HAVE"/>
```

I need to change the access to the page, satisfying that url pattern as well as store new rules. The issue is that specifying those rules via `xml-config` cannot be changed in runtime dynamically. Is it possible to implement at all?

Comment: You can create custom filter and for every attempt to access some url you can check against the database(or something faster) if the user can access the url or not.

Comment: @Evgeni Well, I thought about it. But maybe we can do better... I mean just override some Spring Security's interface and provide custom behavior.

Comment: Can you explain what you are ultimately trying to accomplish? Changing security rules after the fact seems a little odd.

Comment: @Bill For the rule _admin_ I need to provide the ability to create and edit current rules dynamically.

Comment: You may want to consider filtering rather than just changing the underlying rules. Consider the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353994/custom-access-rules-for-spring-security